# How to change the logo on login page on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: linux, debian

I'm using Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian OS. Upon turning on my machine, the system asks me to enter my username and password. So on that specific page, there is an official Raspberry Pi logo. I would like to change that logo to my own logo. Is there any solution to that?

Here is an image to better understand what I'm trying to do:

[Here is an image to better understand which logo I'm attempting to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z29z.jpg)

Comment: That is the LightDM theme. The config file for it may be located in /etc/lightdm.

Comment: Thank you so much @BenSimmons. I'm supposed to make the changes in the pi-greeter.conf file.